# c string copy with strncpy

Tags: c, string

I am really frustrated about strncpy function. I did something like this:

```
char *md5S; //which has been assign with values, its length is 44
char final[32];
strncpy(final,md5S,32);
```

but somehow the length of `char final[]` became more than 32 after.
What should I do here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to leave room for the null character

```
char final[33];
strncpy(final,md5S,32);
final[32] = '\0';
```

Comment: oh, right, thank you so much, can't believe i spent so much time with it

Answer (score 6):

`strncpy` does not NUL-terminate the copied string if the source string is as long as or longer than `n` characters. If you have access to it, you can use `strlcpy`, which will NUL terminate for you.

Do this instead:

```
strncpy(dst, src, dstlen - 1);
dst[dstlen - 1] = '\0';
```

OR

```
strlcpy(dst, src, dstlen);
```

where, for a char array, `dstlen = sizeof(dst)`.

Answer (score 2):

If your output buffer isn't large enough to copy all of the source string and its trailing NUL then the output string will not be NUL terminated.

In your case, the MD5 is 33 bytes including the NUL, so the NUL isn't copied. When you read the string back you're reading past the end of your buffer.

Make final 33 bytes long, and ALWAYS add a NUL to the last character in the destination when using strncpy.

```
int n = 32;
char *src = "some really really long, more than 32 chars, string."
char dst[n+1];

strncpy(dst, src, n);
dst[n] = '\0';
```