# How can I copy the contents of argv[] into a c style string?

Tags: c++, string, unix, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a program that takes several arguments at runtime to append text to a file.

The program produces a segmentation fault at runtime. Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //error checking
    if (argc < 1 || argc > 4) {
        cout << "Usage: -c(optional - clear file contents) <Filename>, message to write"    << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* filename[64];
    char* message[256];

    //set variables to command arguments depending if -c option is specificed
    if (argc == 4) {
        strcpy(*filename, argv[2]);
        strcpy(*message, argv[3]);
    } else {
        strcpy(*filename, argv[1]);
        strcpy(*message, argv[2]);
    }

    int fd; //file descriptor 

    fd = open(*filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00000); //open file if it doesn't exist    then create one
    fchmod(fd, 00000);

    return 0;
}
```

I am still quite a beginner and I'm having immense trouble understanding c strings.  What's the difference between char* and char[] and char* []?

UPDATE:

The code still throws a segmentation fault, here is my revised code:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {

//error checking
if (argc < 1 || argc > 4) {
cout << "Usage: -c(optional - clear file contents) <Filename>, message to write"      << endl;
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

char filename[64];
char message[256];

 //set variables to command arguments depending if -c option is specificed
 if (argc == 4)
{
strncpy(filename, argv[2], 64);
strncpy(message, argv[3], 256);
}
 else
 {
strncpy(filename, argv[1], 64);
strncpy(message, argv[2], 256);
 }

 int fd; //file descriptor 

 fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00000); //open file if it doesn't exist then create one
 fchmod(fd, 00000);


 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: You get points for providing a complete attempt at the program; plenty to learn, but you were close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char* filename[64]` creates an array of 64 pointers. You intend to create space for a string with 64 characters -  this would be `char filename[64]`. Because you only allocated space for pointers, and never made the pointers point to any memory, you get a seg fault.

Solution: use `char filename[64];`

This creates a block of 64 bytes for your string; the value `filename` points to the start of this block and can be used in a copy operation

```
strcpy(filename, argv[2]);
```

I would strongly recommend using the "copy no more than n characters" function - this prevents a really long argument from causing buffer overflow. Thus

```
strncpy(filename, argv[2], 64);
```

would be safer. Even better

```
strncpy(filename, argv[2], 63);
filename[63] = '\0';
```

This guarantees that the copied string is null terminated.

You have the same problem with `message`. I don't think you need the code repeating...

Let me know if you need more info.

**UPDATE**
Today I learnt about the existence of `strlcpy` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7523042/1967396). It will take care of including the `NUL` string terminator even when the original string was longer than the allocated space. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#strlcpy) for a more complete discussion, including the reasons why this function is not available on all compilers (which is of course a major drawback if you are trying to write portable code).

Comment: Great answer! I understand. What would be the output of *filename? It is all a little confusing since the syntax for strcpy states (char* dest, char* src) so I assume that is how you declare c strings.

Comment: "The output of filename"? The character string (the block of memory pointed to by the `filename` pointer would contain the characters that were pointed to by `argv[2]`, up to and including the terminating `'\0'`. The syntax for `strcpy` is `strcpy(char *dest, const char *source);` which is not exactly what you just wrote... See for example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: As for "how you declare C strings" - a C string is referenced with a _pointer_ to a _block of memory_ (that you need to make sure is allocated, and big enough), _terminated with a `'\0'` character (for which you also need space). There are different techniques to allocate the space; the `filename[64]` is one (note - this is big enough for a 63 character string _plus the terminating `'\0'`_), or `const char myString = "hello world";` if you don't intend to change it (memory is allocated for you), or you start with `char myString;` and follow with `myString = malloc(100);` to create space.

Comment: @Floris - awesome explaination.Every 'C' teacher should teach like this :)

Comment: @Purisima - thanks a lot. I have been fighting pointers and such for over 20 years - I k ow how bewildering they can be until the penny drops. Just trying to help a fellow passenger on the road to code...

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged this as C++ (and no one has yet mentioned it):

`argv` is already a C-style array, so there is no need to copy it to another (unless you just want to waste space).  If you really wanted to copy it into something, a `std::string` object would be a better approach:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // assuming your conditional checks are already done here ...
    std::string filename = argv[1];
    std::string message = argv[2];
    // do something
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for making the obvious point "you don't actually _need_ to copy the `argv` for your program to work!

Answer (score 2):

Your variables `filename` and `message` are `char` **pointer** arrays, not C-style strings (which should be null-terminated `char` arrays). So you need to declare their type as:

```
char filename[64];
char message[256];
```

and use `strcpy` as:

```
strcpy(filename, argv[2]);
strcpy(message, argv[3]);
```

the call to `open` is similar:

```
fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00000);
```

Comment: So basically I had an array full of pointers pointing to NULL?

Comment: @Revoo You had an aray full of **un-initialized** `char` pointers.

Answer (score 2):

*>>> I am still quite a beginner and I'm having immense trouble understanding c strings. What's the difference between char* and char[] and char* []?*

Pointers are hard to understand the first time you encounter them.

- char is a single byte in memory
- char* is a pointer to memory (could be a single byte or an array of characters)
- char[] is an array of characters, can be pointed at char*
- char*[] is an array of pointers to char

When you have a variable filename, *filename dereferences that variable, which means that it is not the pointer, but the thing pointed at.

- *filename is of type char, not valid parameter for strcpy, which is where your segfault occurs
- *message is of type char, not valid parameter for strcpy, which is where your next segfault would occur
- open(*filename is again a char, which is not a valid parameter for open

You mostly had the program right.  the problem was your lack of clarity about how to use a pointer.  Here is your code, revised a bit to work.  I commented out the broken parts so you could compare broken to fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //char* filename[64];
    //char* message[256];
    char filename[64]; //declare filename, point it at char[64]
    char message[256]; //declare message, point it at char[256]
    int fd; //file descriptor 

    printf("argc %d\n",argc);
    //error checking
    if ( (argc < 1) || (argc > 4) )
    {
        //cout << "Usage: -c(optional - clear file contents) <Filename>, message to write"    << endl;
printf("Usage: -c(optional - clear file contents) <Filename>, message to write\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int argi=1;
    if( !strcmp(argv[argi],"-c") ) { argi++; } //clear
    //set variables to command arguments depending if -c option is specificed
    if (argc == 4)
    {
        //strcpy(*filename, argv[argi++]);
        //strcpy(*message, argv[argi++]);
        strcpy(filename, argv[argi++]);
        strcpy(message, argv[argi++]);
    }
    else
    {
        //strcpy(*filename, argv[argi++]);
        //strcpy(*message, argv[argi++]);
        strcpy(filename, argv[argi++]);
        strcpy(message, argv[argi++]);
    }

    //fd = open(*filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00000); //open file if it doesn't exist    then create one
    if( !(fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 00000)) ) //open file if it doesn't exist    then create one
    {
        //always check for failure to open
        //and emit error if file open fails
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //fchmod(fd, 00000);
    write(fd,message,strlen(message));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when no arguments given. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> I am still quite a beginner and I'm having immense trouble understanding c strings. What's the difference between char* and char[] and char* []?

The short answer to your explicit question is that `char*` and `char[]` can both be used as C-strings. `char* []` on the other hand is an array of `C-strings`.